# Receive a prize in/on/for a contest

Tags: prepositions, collocation

What is the proper way to say that someone received a prize / achieved a certain rank as a result of his participation in a contest or competition? I would also like a brief explanation, if it's more about it than being a mere collocation.

Comment: Does the word *won* suffice?

Comment: Not really. What if someone took the second, the third prize, or even a lousy but somehow notable honorary mention? _Won_ seems not that proper to me...

Comment: Besides gold, Olympians can **win** silver or bronze. This usage seems a bit contradictory, since unadorned *win* means take the single highest honor, but it’s perfectly idiomatic, at least in American English.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you enter **into** a contest, and you receive a prize **in** a contest. So, I'd guess it's just a combination of those two collocations.

But, on second thought...
You received the prize because you were in the contest; or, in other words, you received the prize because you were **part of** the contest.

So, "for" doesn't work because that would imply you received a prize because you created / held a contest, and "on" wouldn't work because it doesn't establish the important fact that you were actually a participant **in** the contest (also, partly because both of those other prepositions would be jarring. I've never heard anyone use anything other than "in" in this context).

Answer (score 0):

One wins a prize for an achievement.
Example: "Joey won first prize for his poem "Rat Fink" in the school literary competition."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Joey was **awarded** first prize for his poem "Rat Fink" in the school
> literary competition.

**Award** (v.)

> To give money or a prize following an official decision
>
> *Carlos was awarded first prize in the essay competition.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/award)

> To grant as merited or due:
>
> *Awarded prizes to the winners.* [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=award)

---

> Because of the large number of class B riders entered, the promoting
> Meteor club decided to **award** trophies to fourth and fifth place finishers. [*American Motorcyclist*, Dec. 1962](https://books.google.com/books?id=f_oDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=awarded%20fifth%20place&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNwMKw-uOAAxWaMlkFHeQzB2MQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=awarded%20fifth%20place&f=false)